# Custom Profile Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

I have a custom membership provider I'm using for a website I'm developing and I have numerous errors, and they all say something about on the the methods being used.  Here is one of the errors:

Error #   'WebOrder.CustomMembershipProvider' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider.FindUsersByEmail(string, int, int, out int)'   C:\Users\Jschoff\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebOrder\WebOrder\Models\CustomMembershipProvider.cs

I don't know what exactly is causing this, but here is the code for the customprovider class I'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebOrder
{
  public class CustomMembershipProvider : System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider
  {
    public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out System.Web.Security.MembershipCreateStatus status)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override System.Web.Security.MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override string GetUserNameByEmail(string email)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you inherit from a concrete class like `SqlMembershipProvider`? Apart from that, you have implemented a custom membership-provider, not a custom profile-provider(title).

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement this method `FindUsersByEmail` Method

It's declared abstract in MembershipProvider

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.findusersbyemail(v=vs.80).aspx

Link about all methods of your custom provider :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider_methods(v=vs.80).aspx

Add this code

```
public override MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail (
    string emailToMatch,
    int pageIndex,
    int pageSize,
    out int totalRecords
)
{
  .....
}
```